# How to fix TLS error on www.fedex.com when using uTls?

Tags: go, go-http

Can someone help me with fixing my TLS using uTls in go? Whenever I try a GET request for https://www.fedex.com/ I get:

```
Get "https://www.fedex.com/": uTlsConn.Handshake() error: remote error: tls: internal error
```

Here is my code:

```
func tls_connection(URL string) *http.Response {

    cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)

    client := &http.Client{
         Jar: cookieJar
}

    tlsConn.SetSNI(URL)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", URL, nil)
    req.Header.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")

    // the client.do wraps the request
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        fmt.Println(string(body))
    }
    return resp
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            tlsConn.SetSNI(URL)
```

The value for SNI should be the hostname (`www.fedex.com`) and not the URL (`https://www.fedex.com`). This works:

```
            u,_ := url.Parse(URL)
            tlsConn.SetSNI(u.Host)
```

Comment: Hey it didnt work. I get ```Get "www.fedex.com": unsupported protocol scheme ""```

Comment: @jjboi8708: It worked for me with __exactly__ the changes to your code I've posted. I have no idea what you did compared to this. But maybe you've just set URL to `www.fedex.com` from `https://www.fedex.com`? This would not work since URL is also used in `NewRequest` where the `https://...` is important.

Comment: Ohhh nvm it worked. And yeah you were right I changed the URL with the parsed one in the NewRequest. Thank you!